# How to disable products that are not assigned to a category?

Tags: magento, categories, product, observers

Could someone assist with this issue I am having please... I need to disable all products that are not assigned to a category in Magento but the problem is there are some 10,000+ products that I will need to sort through.

I would like to ask what the best approach would be so I could at least begin to solve the problem.

Would it be possible to set all products to disabled if they are not assigned to a category using an Observer? Should I echo the list of unassigned products in a loop then set the status to disabled...

I'm not sure how to go about this one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to do this is using Magento collections.

Create a new PHP file, include `Mage.php`, initialize the application and make your changes.

It might take a while depending on product count.

I think you want to do something like that:

```
require_once('../app/Mage.php');
Mage::init();

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$store_id = 1;

foreach ($product as $prod)
{
    if ($prod->getCategoryIds() == NULL)
    {

        Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')
                 ->updateProductStatus($prod->getId(), $store_id, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);

    }
}
```